# How to make a google analytics reporting API request from a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics-api, gatsby, use-effect

I am trying to build an analytics dashboard with React/Gatsby and the Google Analytics Reporting API v4. I have included the scripts in my layout component from the [google api quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js).

I know it's loading on the page, because in the browser developer tools console I can access `window.gapi` and the google sign in button appears correctly. But in my page component, I have a useEffect hook. When the component mounts, I want to make a request using `window.gapi.client.request(...)`.

I tried wrapping the request in this: `if (typeof window !== undefined) { ... }` as per the [gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/#how-to-check-if-window-is-defined)

Layout.js

```
      <Helmet>
        <meta
          name="google-signin-client_id"
          content="MYCLIENTID"
        />
        <meta
          name="google-signin-scope"
          content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"
        />
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
      </Helmet>
```

Index.js

```
  useEffect(querySuccessfulSubmissions, [])

  function querySuccessfulSubmissions() {
    if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
      window.gapi.client
        .request({
          path: "/v4/reports:batchGet",
          root: "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/",
          method: "POST",
          body: {
            reportRequests: [
              {
                viewId: "MYVIEWID",
                samplingLevel: "LARGE",
                dateRanges: [
                  {
                    startDate: "365daysAgo",
                    endDate: "yesterday",
                  },
                ],
                metrics: [
                  {
                    expression: `ga:goal1Completions`,
                    alias: "",
                  },
                ],
                dimensions: [
                  {
                    name: "ga:yearMonth",
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        })
        .then(response => console.log('success'))
    }
  }
```

I expect to have access to window.gapi from the useEffect hook, but I get `TypeError: window.gapi is undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `setInterval` function to see when `window.gapi` is loaded, then clear it after it loads:

```js
useEffect(window.interval = setInterval(waitForAPI, 1000), [])

waitForAPI() {
    if (window.gapi.client.request !== undefined) {
        querySuccessfulSubmissions();
        clearInterval( window.interval );
    }
}
```